# Let $\ X_1,X_2,X_3$ be an independent continuous random variables

Tags: expected-value

Let $\ X_1,X_2,X_3$ be an independent continuous random variables that are uniformly distributed on $\ [0, n]$.
Let $\ M = M=max⁡{(X_1,X_2,X_3)}$
$\ P(M≤X)=?$ for general $\ X∈[0,n]$
$\ E[M]=?$
I Know that $\ P(X≤t)=F(t)=(t-a)/b=t/n$
$\ P(M≤X)=P(X>M)=1-F(t)=1-M/n$ , **Is that true?**
How I calculate $\ E[M]=?$

Answer (score 1):

To find $P(M\le t)$ :

Calculate it by definition : $P(M\le t) = P(Max\{X_1,X_2,X_3 \} \le t) = P(\cap_{i=1}^3 (X_i\le t) )$ now use independence and finish.

For $E[M]$ , again calculate it by definition.

Differentiate $F_M(t) = P(M\le t)$ to get $f_M(t)$ and then find $E[M] = \int_\Bbb R t f_M(t) dt$.

Comment: $\  a≤X≤b $
$\  P(X_1≤X)=P(a≤X_1≤b)=F(b)-F(a)=
(b-a)/(b-a)-(a-a)/(b-a)=1 $
Therefore , $\  P(M≤X)=1*1*1=1 $
$\ E[M]=∫(X*1)=X^2/2$ 
**I’m not sure about the answer** @infinity

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- $P(M \le x) = P(X_1 \le x, X_2 \le x, X_3 \le x) = P(X_1 \le x) P(X_2 \le x) P(X_3 \le x)$
- Because $M$ is nonnegative you can use the tail sum formula for expectation: $E[M] = \int_0^n P(M \ge t) \, dt$. You can use the result of the previous question to find the integrand.

Comment: $\  a≤X≤b $
$\  P(X_1≤X)=P(a≤X_1≤b)=F(b)-F(a)=(b-a)/(b-a)-(a-a)/(b-a)=1 $
Therefore , $\  P(M≤X)=1*1*1=1 $